# Detect repeating letter in an string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

code for detecting repeating letter in a string.

```
var str="paraven4sr";
var hasDuplicates = (/([a-zA-Z])\1+$/).test(str)        
alert("repeating string "+hasDuplicates);
```

I am getting "**false"** as output for the above string "**paraven4sr**". But this code works correctly for the strings like "**paraaven4sr".** i mean if the character repeated consecutively, code gives output as "**TRUE"**. how to rewrite this code so that i ll get output as "**TRUE"** when the character repeats in a string

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5cKn/1/)

```
var str="paraven4sr";
var hasDuplicates = (/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test(str)        
alert("repeating string "+hasDuplicates);
```

The regular expression `/([a-zA-Z])\1+$/` is looking for:

- `([a-zA-Z]])` - A letter which it captures in the first group; then
- `\1+` - immediately following it one or more copies of that letter; then
- `$` - the end of the string.

Changing it to `/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/` instead searches for:

- `([a-zA-Z])` - A letter which it captures in the first group; then
- `.*?` - zero or more characters (the `?` denotes as few as possible); until
- `\1` - it finds a repeat of the first matched character.

If you have a requirement that the second match must be at the end-of-the-string then you can add `$` to the end of the regular expression but from your text description of what you wanted then this did not seem to be necessary.

Comment: If you want 3 matches, simply put \1\1, if you want 4 matches put \1\1\1 in the regex :)

Comment: @ MT0  here is a question regarding something similar. If i have x="1001" and use x.match(/(\d)\1+/g) --> i get the "00"  ... but if i use it without the global I get two matches "00" and "0"... can you explain that?

Comment: @carinlynchin See the [documentation for match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) it is explained there. A global match does not return the capturing groups just the matched sub-string(s), a non-global match returns the matched sub-string and the capturing groups within that sub-string.

Comment: @MT0 When I use your solution I get: "SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.". What changes should I make to make it work?

Comment: @GiaFil7 It works in strict mode - `(function(){
'use strict';
alert("repeating string "+(/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test("paraven4sr"));
})()` runs without errors.

Comment: @MT0 It doesn't seem to work in freeCodeCamp... I'll talk to them instead. Thanks!

Comment: @MT0 This regex will not work it we will use `String.match()` method on `Cookbosoks`. It should return `soks` as well but it is only returning `["oo", "kbosok"]`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Regular expression matches do not work like that; they start looking for the next match after the end of the previous match (rather than the behaviour you are hoping for of starting looking from the character after the start of the previous match and finding nested or overlapping matches).

Comment: @MT0 Yes, so to achieve this what regex we can use ? Can you please guide or help.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Use a zero-width match: `findReapeatingLetters = value => Array.from(value.matchAll(/(?=(([a-zA-Z]).*?\2))/g), a => a[1])` then `findReapeatingLetters("Cookbosoks")` outputs `["oo", "okbo", "kbosok", "oso", "soks"]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var str = "paraven4sr";
function checkDuplicate(str){
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        var re = new RegExp("[^"+ str[i] +"]","g");
        if(str.replace(re, "").length >= 2){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
alert(checkDuplicate(str));
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/pwGp4/1/)

Comment: Good, What is "g" in this line "        var re = new RegExp("[^"+ str[i] +"]","g");
"

Answer (score 1):

To just test duplicate alphanumeric character (including underscore `_`):

```
console.log(/(\w)\1+/.test('aab'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
String.prototype.count=function(s1) { 
   return (this.length - this.replace(new RegExp(s1,"g"), '').length) / s1.length;
}

"aab".count("a") > 1
```

EDIT: Sorry, just read that you are not searching for a function to find whether a letter is found more than once but to find whether a letter is a duplicate. Anyway, I leave this function here, maybe it can help. Sorry ;)