# Count repeated letters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck with the following problem:
I need to  find repeated characters in a string.
Basically what I want is regular expression that will match like that

```
hello - ["ll"];
here  - ["ee"];
happiness   -  ["pp","ss"];
pupil  -  ["pp"];
```

I have the one that matches consecutive repeated characters

```
  /([a-z])\1+/g
```

Also the one that will match repeated chars and everything  between them like  this one

```
   /([a-z])(?:.*)\1+/g
```

But cant figure out the correct one.

Comment: So from the examples you want to count characters, and return any that appear more than once? Should be doable with just simple iteration and an object.

Comment: what should be the output of `hellloo`?

Comment: Sorry - I closed this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513274/detect-repeating-letter-in-an-string-in-javascript) but re-reading your expected output I see that you want something different. I've reopened your question. As @adeneo said your best bet is probably to iterate over the characters rather than use a regular expression.

Comment: Not a regex, but here's what I'd do -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8czwdq5j/

Comment: Can there be more than 2 repetitions like `assassin`? If yes that should be output?

Comment: A good test (similar to `assassin`) would be `banana`, which should return `aaa` and `nn`. Most of the solutions so far return `anana` or just `aa`

Comment: @karthikmanchala expected output for hellloo is ["lll", "oo"]. My first regexp can do this

Comment: @anubhava the input can be any  string - assassin too. Tht output for it should be  ["aa", "ssss"]

Comment: @adeneo your solution does solve the problem. still I'm wondering  whether the same  result can be  achieved with  regular expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
([a-zA-Z]).*(\1)
```

[Demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/eR8cP5/1)

---

Since you have clarified that you are looking for a solution that will handle something other than double letters in a string, you should use a non-regex approach such as:

Build an associative array with the count of the characters in the string:

```
var obj={}
var repeats=[];
str='banana'

for(x = 0, length = str.length; x < length; x++) {
    var l = str.charAt(x)
    obj[l] = (isNaN(obj[l]) ? 1 : obj[l] + 1);
}

console.log(obj)
```

Prints

```
{ b: 1, a: 3, n: 2 }
```

Then build an array of your specifications:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key]>1) {
        repeats.push(new Array( obj[key]+ 1 ).join( key ));
    }
}
console.log(repeats)
```

Prints:

```
[ 'aaa', 'nn' ]
```

Comment: it returns ["assa", "ss"] for assassin and ["anana"] for banana. But I  expect  ["aa","ssss"] and ["aaa","nn"] respectively

Comment: I assume  there is no way to solve the problem merely using regular expression is there?

Comment: For your example words, you can use a regex. For words with more than a single repeat of a letter such as 'banana' and 'assassin', regex would have to be combined with code. If you are going to use code, you might as well just use a string associative array which is what you would use with a rex anyway.

Comment: this is an interview answer.

Answer (score 4):

This method also works well!!

```
let myString = 'abababc';
let result = {};
for (let str of myString) {
  result[str] = result.hasOwnProperty(str) ? result[str] + 1 : 1;
}
console.log(result);
```

The result will be like this ***{a: 3, b: 3, c: 1}***

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario you second solution seems better. You can get the second letter by other capture group

Regex you be (it is your 2nd RegEx with more one capture group):

```
/([a-z])(?:.*)(\1)+/g
```

```js
var re = /([a-z])(?:.*)(\1)+/g; 
var str = ['hello', 'here', 'happiness', 'pupil'];
var m;
var result = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  result[i] = str[i] + "->";
  while ((m = re.exec(str[i])) !== null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
          re.lastIndex++;
      }
      // View your result using the m-variable.
      // eg m[0] etc.
    result[i] += m[1];
    result[i] += m[2] + ",";
  }
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result.join("</br>");
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {};
var str = "this is my string";
for (var i = 97; i < 97 + 26; i++) 
  obj[String.fromCharCode(i)] = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  obj[str.charAt(i).toLowerCase()]++;
}
```

From there you can say `obj["a"]` to get the number of occurrences for any particular letter.

Answer (score 1):

More complicated than a RegExp solution, however it properly handles `banana` and `assassin`, where there are two overlapping groups of characters.

This does make use of [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which means this exact solution doesn't support <=IE8, however it can be polyfilled quite easily.

```js
function findDuplicateCharacters(input) {
  // Split the string and count the occurrences of each character
  var count = input.split('').reduce(function(countMap, word) {
    countMap[word] = ++countMap[word] || 1;
    return countMap;
  }, {});

  // Get the letters that were found, and filter out any that only appear once.
  var matches = Object.keys(count)
    .filter(function (key) { return (count[key] > 1); })
    // Then map it and create a string with the correct length, filled with that letter.
    .map(function (key) {
      return new Array(count[key] + 1).join(key);
    });

  return matches;
}

var results = ['hello', 'here', 'happiness', 'pupil', 'banana'].map(findDuplicateCharacters);

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results.join('<br />');
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var re = /([a-z])(?:.*)(\1)+/g; 
var str = ['aaaccbcdd'];
var m;
var result = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  result[i] = str[i] + "->";
  while ((m = re.exec(str[i])) !== null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
          re.lastIndex++;
      }
      // View your result using the m-variable.
      // eg m[0] etc.
    result[i] += m[1];
    result[i] += m[2] + ",";
  }
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result.join("</br>");
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function charCount(str){
    let arr = str.split('');
    return arr.reduce((a,p)=>{
        a[p] = a[p] ? (a[p]+1) : 1;
        return a;
    },{});
};
```

Comment: You should describe your code / give some explanation with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this method

const countRepeatChar = (str) => {
  let obj = {};

  if (str) {
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (obj[str[i]]) {
        obj[str[i]] += obj[str[i]];
      } else {
        obj[str[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    console.log(obj);
  }
};
countRepeatChar("aabcddeee");
```