# finding the word with most repeated letters from a string containing a sentence in python

Tags: python

I want to find a word with the most repeated letters given an input a sentence.
I know how to find the most repeated letters given the sentence but I'm not able how to print the word.

For example:

this is an elementary test example

should print

elementary

```py
def most_repeating_word(strg):
    words =strg.split()
    for words1 in words:
        dict1 = {}
        max_repeat_count = 0
        for letter in words1:
            if letter not in dict1:
                dict1[letter] = 1
            else:
                dict1[letter] += 1
            if dict1[letter]> max_repeat_count:
                max_repeat_count = dict1[letter]
                most_repeated_char = letter
                result=words1
      return result
```

Comment: why are you not able to print the word?

Comment: prints the last word of the sentence always, i'm not able to print the word that have most repeated characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting the most_repeat_count variable for each word to 0. You should move that upper in you code, above first for loop, like this:

```
def most_repeating_word(strg):
    words =strg.split()
    max_repeat_count = 0
    for words1 in words:
        dict1 = {}
        for letter in words1:
            if letter not in dict1:
                dict1[letter] = 1
            else:
                dict1[letter] += 1
            if dict1[letter]> max_repeat_count:
                max_repeat_count = dict1[letter]
                most_repeated_char = letter
                result=words1
    return result
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes works, thank you. I added another loop and forgot that.

Comment: Great, marking it as the answer would be appreciated :) @Florent

Answer (score 0):

Interesting exercise! +1 for using `Counter()`. Here's my suggestion also making use of `max()` and its `key` argument, and the `*` unpacking operator.

For a final solution note that this (and the other proposed solutions to the question) don't currently consider case, other possible characters (digits, symbols etc) or whether more than one word will have the maximum letter count, or if a word will have more than one letter with the maximum letter count.

```
from collections import Counter

def most_repeating_word(strg):
    # Create list of word tuples: (word, max_letter, max_count)
    counters = [ (word, *max(Counter(word).items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
                 for word in strg.split() ]
    max_word, max_letter, max_count = max(counters, key=lambda item: item[2])
    return max_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex instead.  It is simple and easy. Iteration is an expensive operation compared to regular expressions.

Please refer to the solution for your problem in this post:
[Count repeated letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512744/count-repeated-letters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
word="SBDDUKRWZHUYLRVLIPVVFYFKMSVLVEQTHRUOFHPOALGXCNLXXGUQHQVXMRGVQTBEYVEGMFD"

def most_repeating_word(strg):
    dict={}
    max_repeat_count = 0
    for word in strg:
        if word not in dict:
            dict[word] = 1
        else:
            dict[word] += 1
        if dict[word]> max_repeat_count:
            max_repeat_count = dict[word]
    result={}
    for word, value in dict.items():
        if value==max_repeat_count:
            result[word]=value
    return result

print(most_repeating_word(word))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).