# How to encode string in javaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am doing an exercise, the task is: I need to write a function which takes an argument a string and returns encoded string, for example: aaabbcccc -> should return 3a2b4c.
I wrote the function, I created an object where I have all characters counted but I don't know how to return value and key converted into the string. Here is my code

```js
function encoded(plainText) {
  let charMap = {}
  for (let char of plainText) {
    char = char.toLowerCase()

    if (!charMap[char]) {
      charMap[char] = 1
    } else {
      charMap[char]++
    }
  }

  console.log(charMap)
}

encoded('aaabbcccc');
```

Comment: Object properties are inherently unordered, so you should not collect stats if you need the same order. Also, what should be the output if input was `aabbbaaa`?

Comment: I found the solution :
``` let str = '';
    for (let p in charMap) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(charMap, p)) {
            str +=charMap[p] +p;
        }
    }
  return  str;
```
but my mistake the function if passed string is "aabaa"return them like "4a1b"  but should be "2a1b2a" how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count repeated letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512744/count-repeated-letters-in-a-string)

Comment: You can just use object.entries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries this should be easiest I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string could contain duplicate chars, for example `aabbbbaaa`, you'd need to use an array of stats for each occurrence of the symbol

Also, object properties do not have order and might be "reorganized" by the runtime for performance reasons. For example, if your input string could contain numbers itself `aaa111bbb`

```js
function encoded(plainText) {
  const freq = [];
 
  
  // 1. collect char frequency for each occurrence
  for (const char of plainText) {
    const last = freq[freq.length - 1];
    
    if (!last || last.char !== char) {
      freq.push({ char, count: 1})
    } else {
      last.count++;
    }
  }
  
  // 2. stringify 
  return freq.reduce((result, { char, count }) => `${result}${count}${char}`, '')
}

console.log(encoded('aabbbbccccddaa'))
```

Comment: Thank you that works, so I should use an array instead of the object, I didn't know, I am beginner and prepare for the interview.

Comment: If you need ordered keys you need an array or a `Map` that keeps the order. For example `console.log(Object.keys({a: 1, 1: 2, b: 3}))` the order of keys would be not `a, 1, b` but `1, a, b` because runtime can reorganise the order of keys.

Answer (score -1):

Maintain the count in a variable and test if the next letter in the sequence matches the current letter resetting the count if it's not.

```js
function encoded(plainText) {
  
  let out = '';
  let count = 0;
  
  const text = plainText.toLowerCase();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    ++count;
    if (text[i + 1] !== text[i]) {
      out += `${count}${text[i]}`;
      count = 0;
      continue;
    }
  }
  
  return out;

}

console.log(encoded('aaabbccccABBCc'));
```

Comment: This will cause issues when a string contains the same character range on multiple places, for example "aabbbccbb".

Comment: Well, it will now the OP has changed the required output from the question I actually answered.

Comment: Yes, it works well the only thing is if string passed is "aabaacc" the function should return "2a1b2a2c" but it returns "4a1b2c" how to fix it?

Comment: That's something you should have mentioned in your question, and requires a completely different solution - an object won't help you here.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function encoded(plainText) {
  let charMap = {}
  for (let char of plainText) {
    char = char.toLowerCase()

    if (!charMap[char]) {
      charMap[char] = 1
    } else {
      charMap[char]++
    }
  }
  
  let output = '';
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(charMap) ) {
    output += `${value}${key}`;
  }

  console.log(output)
}

encoded('aaabbcccc');
```

Comment: This will cause issues when a string contains the same character range on multiple places, for example "aabbbccbb".

Comment: That's true, I did not optimise it for any edge cases or scenarios that were not specified. I just showed OP how to get all entries from an object. If any other requirement comes up, they might be able to implement this on their own or make a new question.