# Return a word from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, split

I have a string of 3 words `'walking running swimmming'` and I want to return only those who have double letters. Well, I found a solution how to do this, but I'm stuck on separating the words. Any ideas? I've tried .map (returns 'not a function'), .split(). Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
P.S. var repeats = /([a-zA-Z])\1/;
```

Comment: Does "swimmming" count as having double letters? Is it strictly double letters, where 3 in a row don't count? Or did you just misspell "swimming"?

Comment: You could perhaps split the words with `var words = 'walking running swimmming'.Split(' ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want it something like this:

```js
let result = 'walking running swimmming'
        .split(' ')  // turn into array
        .filter(s => /([a-zA-Z])\1/.test(s))  // filter out elements of array
        
console.log(result)
```

returns

```
["running", "swimmming"]
```

Comment: Console still returns that .map is not a function. You can try it youself on  [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/my-aunt-sally/) . That's what I had written before I asked the question. [codepen](https://codepen.io/berezovsky/pen/OOrJNV?editors=0010)

Comment: I added a snippet. If your browser is saying map/filter are not a functions, you may be using an old browser, or may have somehow overwritten Array.prototype.map with something that's not a function (i.e. Array.prototype.map = undefined; will surely cause map to stop working.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just run `.split(" ")` on your string and then iterate through the list to perform your check

[help if you need it](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Split the words into an array by the space. Use `.filter` to return only those that have a repeated letter. Inside the filter, test if it has a repeated letter with regex and `.test`. Returns true if it does, adding it to the new array.

```
function doubles(words) {
    const arr = words.split(" ");
    return arr.filter(word => (/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/).test(word));
}

doubles("walking running swimming");  // returns ["running", "swimming"]
```

Regex for the test was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513274/detect-repeating-letter-in-an-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more performance efficient answer, but I'd probably go for this one because it's minimalist.

```
'walking running swimming'
  .split(' ')
  .filter(word => /(.)\1/.test(word));
```

**Explanations**

`String.prototype.split` returns an array of words.

`Array.prototype.filter` calls a lambda function for each element of the array. If the function returns true, that element is kept, else it is discarded. The filtered array is then returned.

`RegExp.prototype.test` returns true if the string matches the regex.

`word => ...` is a short notation for `function (word) { return ... }`

`/(.)\1/` is a RegExp which matches strings that contain any character twice in a row. You could use `a-zA-Z` instead of `.` if you prefer, it will have different results if your strings might contain other characters.

---

So with that sample string, this is what happens:

1. `'walking running swimming'` becomes `['walking', 'running', 'swimming']`
2. For each element of the array, the `word => ...` lambda is called.

   - `walking` doesn't have a sequence of two repeated characters, so `test` will return false.
   - `running` and `swimming` will `test` true.
3. `filter` returns an array of words that tested true, `['running', 'swimming']`

Answer (score 1):

You can get multiple matches from a string (`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) :

```js
console.log( 'walking running swimmming'.match(/\w*(\w)\1\w*/g) )

console.log( 'walking running swimmming'.match(/[a-z]*([a-z])\1[a-z]*/gi) )
```

To match words with only 2 repeating characters:

```js
console.log( 'walking running swimmming'.replace(/(.)\1\1+/g, 0).match(/\w*(\w)\1\w*/g) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var str = 'walking running swimmming';
var strArr = str.split(' ');
strArr.forEach(function(word){
  if(word.match(/([A-Za-z])\1/)){
    console.log(word);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var words = "walking running swimming".split(' ') 
// ["walking", "running", "swimming"]
var double_letter_words = words.filter(
      function(w) { 
            for (i = 0; i < w.length - 1; i++) { 
               if (w[i] == w[i+1]) return true 
            }; 
            return false; }) 
 // ["running", "swimming"]
 console.log(double_letter_words);
```

I should note that while I didn't use your regular expression (like other answers), it does correctly filter the words and has slightly better performance than the other answers, and also is somewhat easier to maintain and modify than a regex.

https://jsperf.com/return-double-letter-words-from-string

Comment: Didn't you read the question he only wants to return only those who have  words which double letters

Comment: He said he was stuck on splitting the string into words.

Comment: @AdeelImran  "but I'm stuck on separating the words".